# Tab bar display through out the project?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

I have a Tab-bar application in iOS Storybords. The UITabbarcontroller is connected to -->4 sets of (UInavigation controller--> UItableview controller). Each UITableviewcontroller cells are connected to multiple UIviewcontrollers to be pushed.

On building the app -The navigation tab appears on the top of the view controllers without any problem. But the Tabbar with 4 items at the bottom is visible ONLY on the first view. The UIviewcontrollers does not display the 4 item Tabbar!??. I have set the bottom bar to tab bar in the attributes inspector. But it doesn't work?

I believe there must be more to it than I understand. Hope somebody helps.

How to display the tabbar through out the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure of your design, but here are a couple of tips that hopefully may help.

storyboard design:

basic tabbar application layout would generally look like this from left to right with the first controller on the left having the little arrow indicating it is the starting controller.

- your first controller should be the tabbar controller
- each tab should be connected to a navigation controller
- each navigation controller should be connected to one or more UIViewControllers or UITableViewControllers.

now, note while there are advanced configurations, this is just the general layout that sets up the app nicely and gives easy push transitions for each tab.

if your app starts off and shows the tabbar and when you select a tab item it should show the view controller for that tab.  if the tabbar is still there, then you are in good shape up to that point.  If you select something on that view controller and it pushes a new view controller on screen and when that happens you lose the tabbar bar, then its likely this is the issue:
  - check your view controllers and look in the object inspector for a check mark called "hides bottom bar on push" - if it is checked - then uncheck it.
If you don't find it there, then inspect your code for your view controllers and look in the startup methods like view did load for the statement: self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;  if you find that command, comment it out or delete it.

It is perfectly ok to hide the tabbar on some view controller pushes if that is your design and makes sense in your application.  Generally, it's a good practice to try and avoid it and leave the tabbar on screen when possible for user experience but sometimes issues like screen size might lead the developer down a path of hiding it for some workflow.

I hope this helps and ties back to your question. if not, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can add tab bar like this way:-

**Appdelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class StartingViewController;

@interface Appdelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    StartingViewController *viewController;

    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet StartingViewController *viewController;

@property (nonatomic,retain) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

-(void)addTabBarToView;

@end
```

**app delegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self addTabBarToView];

    return YES;
}

-(void)addTabBarToView{

    FirstController *first = [[FirstController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstController" bundle:nil];
    first.title = @"First";

    SecondController *second = [[SecondController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondController" bundle:nil];
    second.title = @"Second";

    ThirdController *three = [[ThirdController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdController" bundle:nil];
    first.title = @"Third";

    Forthcontrooler *Four4 = [[Forthcontrooler alloc] initWithNibName:@"Forthcontrooler" bundle:nil];
    second.title = @"Secfor";





   UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:first];

   UINavigationController *navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:second];

   UINavigationController *navigationController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:three];

   UINavigationController *navigationController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:Four4];



    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];        

    tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController1,navigationController2,navigationController3,navigationController4,nil];

    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `UINavigationController`s inside the `UITabbarController`s instead of the other way around

Comment: Your suggestion appeared promising, but I could not get it display. Would you be able to explain little more detail - may be step by step. I greatly appreciate.

Comment: I have embedded the four UINavigationControllers in UITabbarcontroller and then connected one UITableViewcontroller to each navigation controller. But still no luck in displaying the tab bar in the the UIviewcontroller (cames into view on clicking the table-view cell)

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean, but I see that you accepted an answer so I guess you found a solution.